# Dealing with economic significance and statistical significance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

For my thesis I'm regressing idiosyncratic volatility on institutional ownership and several control variables. I run a panel regression with firm fixed effects and get the following result:

```
                             PanelOLS Estimation Summary                              
======================================================================================
Dep. Variable:     Idiosyncratic_Volatility   R-squared:                        0.1163
Estimator:                         PanelOLS   R-squared (Between):              0.0295
No. Observations:                    304881   R-squared (Within):               0.1163
Date:                      Wed, Jun 17 2020   R-squared (Overall):              0.1525
Time:                              16:11:00   Log-likelihood                 8.948e+05
Cov. Estimator:                   Clustered                                           
                                              F-statistic:                      7743.7
Entities:                             10679   P-value                           0.0000
Avg Obs:                             28.550   Distribution:                F(5,294197)
Min Obs:                             1.0000                                           
Max Obs:                             151.00   F-statistic (robust):             420.97
                                              P-value                           0.0000
Time periods:                           152   Distribution:                F(5,294197)
Avg Obs:                             2005.8                                           
Min Obs:                             23.000                                           
Max Obs:                             3178.0                                           
                                                                                      
                                  Parameter Estimates                                   
========================================================================================
                      Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const                    0.1250     0.0037     33.984     0.0000      0.1178      0.1322
Passive Market Share    -0.0101     0.0005    -20.413     0.0000     -0.0110     -0.0091
Log(Market Cap)         -0.0035     0.0002    -19.611     0.0000     -0.0039     -0.0032
Book-to-Market           0.0015     0.0004     3.8860     0.0001      0.0008      0.0023
Amihud Illiquidity      -0.0009     0.0002    -5.8060     0.0000     -0.0012     -0.0006
Momentum                 0.0024     0.0001     16.562     0.0000      0.0021      0.0026
========================================================================================

F-test for Poolability: 40.221
P-value: 0.0000
Distribution: F(10678,294197)

Included effects: Entity
```

The results were quite surprising as all the variables have a low standard error and are significant at 1%. For a sanity check I decided to do scatter plots on the variables. Below you can see the scatter plot between Book-to-Market and Idiosyncratic Volatility:

[image: B-to-M vs IVol]

[image: B-to-M vs IVol Hex]

There is no clear pattern. My suspicion is that the large sample size leads to the model to distinguish even small coefficients from zero. Although this is not necessarily bad, I'm not sure how do I interpret whether they are also economically significant. Would I have to look for literature between the variables to argue that there is a relationship?

Although I've followed some statistics courses, I'm by no means an expert, so please pardon any "newb-ness" evident in my post.

Comment: Re "there is no clear pattern:" One reason is the overlap of points.  Please recreate that scatterplot in a more revealing way, either through partial transparency, greatly shrinking the point size, a hex plot, or even a sunflower plot. Consider adding a robust smooth.

Comment: @whuber I added some alpha to it and decreased the point size. It indeed seems to be a bit clearer now.